# How can I mount a MacOS fusion drive?

Tags: mount, raid, mac, macosx, drive

When viewing the partitions, obviously there are two physical disks, but virtually it's being treated as one disk on MacOS (Fusion drive). How can one mount this on ubuntu? The normal mounting commands seem to error when trying to mount with either one of the data volumes, and don't show up in lsblk with having any filesystem type. I understand that this fusion thing is like Apple's own way of doing RAID, but if the underlying filesystem is HFSplus, how do I mount the RAID like drive group?

EDIT: I only need read access to the data.

Comment: This should be possible but in your commands you need to be explicit and precise about the size of the volume (in bytes).  Check out this answer on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1088110).

Comment: @Nmath huh, that's neat, I'll try that sometime tomorrow.

Comment: Funny that you asked about this because just this week I had to figure out how to mount a HFS+ drive pulled from a broken 2011 macbook pro.  This solution was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Fusion Drive Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_Drive).

> Apple's Fusion Drive design incorporates proprietary features with limited documentation.

Like Intel RST or Windows FastBoot, until the owner (Apple) shares their proprietary technology, it's closed and unusable by Linux. We don't know how you can mount the RAID, since Apple has not disclosed how.

Without documentation, it's unlikely to be reverse-engineered. Even if it were reverse-engineered, there's no assurance that an open solution could be shared without getting lawyers involved for a few years.

Your disk, for the foreseeable future, is readable only by certain Apple-produced hardware running OSX.

(Remember, this is Apple's decision. Not ours. Complain to them.)

**Solution**: You can install Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine on top of the OSX host. The Ubuntu VM would be able to read the files, since the host (OSX) is doing the REAL file access.

**Solution**: You can use an OSX system to copy the data onto a ordinary non-Fusion drive that Ubuntu can read natively.

Comment: That is pretty unfortunate, but thanks